# How to run Flash Debugger without menu and titlebar?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Can I get rid of the title bar and the menu when I run my SWFs in Flash Debugger?
Is there any way?

**Like this:** (red marks what has to go)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can hide menu, but you can pass to **fullscreen mode** using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> (win) / <kbd>Cmd</kbd> (mac) + <kbd>F</kbd> and to quit this mode and return to **normal mode** use <kbd>ESC</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

If it's *really* important to get rid of the window chrome, you can compile it as an AIR app and set it to not render the window chrome.

To do so, first open the Publish Settings window and set the Target property to **AIR for Desktop**. (The actual AIR version will differ depending on what version of the AIR SDK you have installed.) Then click on the wrench icon to edit the AIR settings.

[image: Set target to AIR for Desktop]

In the AIR Settings window, in the General tab, set the Window style property to **Custom Chrome (Opaque)**.

[image: Set window style to Custom Chrome (opaque)]

When you now debug your application, it will run in a chromeless window.

Note that if you do it this way, you will compile against different libraries so certain peculiarities could arise. If you intend to publish this to the web, make sure to only use APIs that are compatible with Flash Player. Also, make sure to remember to reset the target to Flash Player before you do the final export.